# Safety of direct bonding to exterior ground for CSST

Tags: grounding, grounding-and-bonding, bonding, csst

The instructions for my yellow CSST propane line require it to be bonded where the service enters my home. They also specify not to bond at two points, and not to bond at the appliance. The appliance is a stove with an electric oven that is connected to a grounded outlet that is powered from a subpanel. From the point my gas line enters the house, I cannot access the electrical panel. I can, however, run the copper ground along the exterior of the house and bond directly to the main ground that ties upstream into the main panel. Would bonding directly to the main ground outside to the CSST point of entry outside be safe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Certainly

The requirements for CSST bonding only require a single point on the CSST to be bonded with a sufficiently large wire to the main grounding electrode system of the house.  They do *not* care where in the grounding electrode system you tie in at.

Comment: Thank you. How about the safety of what becomes two ground points with the connection to the appliance?

Comment: @aaron.kyle -- the bulk of the current will flow through the much shorter/fatter path to ground provided by the explicit bonding connection

Comment: Thank you for this!